# Issue with bounded in probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, asymptotics

I have tried to prove the following problem that I read in the lecture and it seems not transparent to me.

Suppose that $Y_{i}$ be independent random variables (with $i=1,2,3, \dotsc$). Each has the following probability density function.

$f(y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{c}  & \text{for $y \in (0,c)$}\\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$

for some $0 < c < \infty $.

Then, in this case, is it true that  $Y_{1},Y_{2}, \dotsc$ is bounded in probability? I think it is not bounded in probability even though it may be bounded within the open interval $(0,c)$

If you have any comments/suggestions, I highly appreciate your time and suggestions here.

Comment: Start with a definition of "bounded in probability."  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339135 offers a useful one.

Comment: @whuber   Thank you very much.